# Postgres How to select parent table based on child's last records?

Tags: postgresql, one-to-many

I have a table A(id, name) and B(id, a_id, date) and C(b_id, is_agreed)
A and B have one to one relationship
B and C have one to many relationship

What I want to do is
I'd like to select A table where C's last record's field "is_agreed" is True

What I have been doing so far is

```
SELECT *
FROM A a
JOIN B b on A.id = b.a_id
INNER JOIN C c1 on b.id = c1.b_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C c2 ON ((b.id = c2.b_id) AND (c1.id < c2.id))
WHERE c2.is_agreed = TRUE;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "C's last table's is_agreed field"?

Comment: 1)define `last` ,you'll probably need `b.date`. 2) you'll need `(not) exists(select...from C ...)` or an aggregate or window function.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i just updated the question above.
I meant a field "is_agreed" of last record is True

Comment: @wildplasser I meant last is by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ea1ff1894f1c8a9533131189210eff5)

First select the last `is_agreed = true` value (ordering by `is_agreed DESC` ordered the `true` values to top; after the - because you wrote by id - ordering the highest `b_id` to top). Getting only one record can be done with `LIMIT 1`.

After that simple joining to table `a`

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        b_id
    FROM
        c
    ORDER BY is_agreed DESC, b_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c
JOIN b ON c.b_id = b.id
JOIN a ON b.a_id = a.id
```